# Does Swift have quadratic string concatenation when using var?

Tags: swift, string, mutability

[In the Swift Language Reference, under String Mutability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) it says:

> You indicate whether a particular String can be modified (or mutated) by assigning it to a variable (in which case it can be modified), or to a constant (in which case it cannot be modified)

It's unclear to me if the "it" that is mutable is the *variable* or the *value*.

For example, if I write:

```
var s = ""
for i in 0...100 {
  s += "a"
}
```

Is it akin to creating an `NSMutableString` and calling `appendString` 100 times (i.e. linear cost)?

Or is it akin to creating a series of ever-larger `NSString` instances and combining them with `stringByAppendingString` (i.e. quadratic cost)?

Or perhaps it creates some kind of rope structure behind the scenes, so it's immutable *and* linear in aggregate?

Comment: @MarkDickinson I actually did try that, and it ran way faster than I expected. So that would seem to imply mutable. But, when two mutable variables are set equal to each other, updating one doesn't update the other, which implies immutable. And from a language design perspective it seems really weird to put runtime type information into var-vs-val. So I'm really not sure which it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appending to a collection like this (while `String` is not itself a collection, you're essentially appending to its `characters` view with that code) is linear, not quadratic. A string in Swift has an internal buffer whose size is doubled whenever it fills up, which means you will see fewer and fewer reallocations as you repeatedly append. The documentation describes appending in this way as an "amortized" O(1) operation: most of the time appending is O(1), but occasionally it will need to reallocate the string's storage.

Arrays, sets, and dictionaries have the same behavior, although you can also reserve a specific capacity for an array (using `reserveCapacity(_:)`) if you know you'll be appending many times.

---

All these collections use "copy-on-write" to guarantee value semantics. Here, `x` and `y` share a buffer:

```
let x = "a"
let y = x
```

If you mutate `x`, it gets a new, unique copy of the buffer:

```
x += "b"
// x == "ab"
// y == "a"
```

After that, `x` has its own buffer, so subsequent mutations won't require a copy.

```
x += "c"   // no copy unless buffer is full
```

Comment: This is begging for a link to the stdlib source ;-)

Comment: @jtbandes How about a link to the documentation? ;) https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string#2621389

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail about the semantics of `var string` to justify this answer? For example, why does `var x = "a"; var y = x; x += "b"; print(y)` print "a" instead of "ab" if there's just a common buffer being appended into?

Comment: Strings (and the other collections I mentioned) use "copy-on-write" to guarantee value semantics (i.e., that `y` is unaffected when you mutate `x`). At the beginning, `x` and `y` share a buffer, but when you call `x += "b"`, `x` gets a new, unique copy of the buffer. After that, `x` has its own buffer, so subsequent mutations won't require a copy.

Comment: @NateCook Okay I think I see, so anytime the value of `x` might escape they basically make an immutable copy but defer the cost? That's very interesting... it probably works quite well in most cases, though there's sharp edges like rewriting `x += a` into `var y = x; y += a; x = a;` creating a huge time penalty.

Comment: @NateCook Please mention the copy-on-write detail in your answer. It's crucial, I think.

Comment: @CraigGidney Yes, those kinds of things can cause problems if the compiler can't figure out that it doesn't need the extra reference.